# Identifying Confidential Emails using Gmail API

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I'm currently working on a project that involves processing a large number of emails and identifying whether they are marked as confidential in Gmail. I am using Gmail SDK to fetch the emails but couldn't find anything which can be used to identify a confidential email.
[image]
[image]

Specifically, I have the following questions:

1. Are there any specific Gmail API endpoints or methods that can be used to check if an email is marked as confidential?
2. How can I access the confidentiality status of an email using the Gmail API? Are there any specific properties or metadata fields I should be looking for?
3. Does Gmail API provide information about other sensitive labels or markings attached to an email, such as "Confidential"?
4. Are there any specific scopes or permissions that need to be configured when authenticating my application to access confidential email information?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, code examples, or documentation references that can help me understand the necessary steps and best practices for identifying confidential emails using the Gmail API.

Thank you all for your time and expertise!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. What does `marked as confidential in Gmail` mean? 2. What does `the confidentiality status of an email` mean? 3. What does `information about other sensitive labels or markings attached to an email, such as "Confidential"` mean? 4. In your situation, are you required to use [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides) instead of [Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail)?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike : Please find the answers below : 
1 & 2. I've updated my question with the screenshots which indicates how we can mark an email as confidential. 
So basically with the above setup we can mark any email as confidential and with that gmail doesn't allow the email to get printed or forwarded. 

3. All the emails are marked with different labels for example if we receive an email it will marked as INBOX (/IMPORTANT) etc. More details here : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/list

4. Yes, we have to use Gmail SDK ( which uses Gmail API )

Comment: @Tanaike i think they mean this https://support.google.com/a/answer/7684332?hl=en  Its a good question tbh.   I wonder if its in one of the mail headers or if it has a different encryption type.

Comment: Hi @LindaLawton-DaImTo : That was also my first thought. I did check all headers of a confidential email from Gmail API ( https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get ) but didn't find any header that might help with the identification. 
Btw : I didn't find any difference between the headers ( using the above api ) of a confidential email and a normal email.

Comment: My thinking is that since this is a new feature, Google has yet to update Gmail's REST API with properties or resource endpoints that would allows us to programmatically identify a message as confidential. This is pretty common with Google products, they release a new feature but then API support for that feature comes out months (or sometimes years) later.

Comment: @NitSher01 Thank you for replying. From your added image, I could understand it. I'm worried that in the current stage, this might have not been implemented in Gmail API and Gmail service. But, I would like to believe that this will be implemented in the future update.

Comment: @Linda Lawton - DaImTo Thank you for the information. From your URL, I could understand it. I'm worried that we may have to wait a little longer for implementing it. it is as same as the smart chips.

Comment: @Tanaike I agree with you.